# Why does Cascade return so many faces?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV from its examples, but I've met a big problem with `objectDetection.cpp`. I ran it on my laptop, but it returns me a huge number of faces in the first run and it could not continue to run another round in `while`. Has anybody encountered something like this before?

Before defect:

[image]

After defect:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the input image?

Comment: check your VS studio configuration. it is not related with the code

Answer (score 0):

- Try this.May be this will help you.

  ```
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, rejectLevels, levelWeights,
          1.1, 3, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(16, 16), Size(0, 0), true);
  ```